# Entity Framework database first - result class column generation issue

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, ado.net

My stored procedure is returning a result from 2 select statements based on the condition (as shown below). When I generate the `.edmx` file input and result class for this stored procedure, in the result class I'm only getting ID, name and DateIn. The `DateOut` column is missing from the result class. Please help me to get this column in the `.edmx` using Entity Framework database-first approach.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStocks]  
    (@id INTEGER)  
AS    
BEGIN  
    IF @id = 2
       SELECT ID, name, DateIn 
       FROM dbo.StcokIn
    ELSE
       SELECT ID, name, DateOut 
       FROM dbo.StockOut;
END
```

I generated the `.edmx` file, but I didn't get `DateOut` column in the result class:

```
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    using System;

    public partial class GetStcoks_Result
    {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string DateIn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to get missing `DateOut` column in `GetStcoks_Result` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 99%, the cause is the different column names of 'Date'.
The first statement results in three columns:

```
[ID] [name] [DateIn]
```

The second one:

```
[ID] [name] [DateOut]
```

EF maps columns to properties by name, so in the second case it can't map `DateOut` column to `DateIn`property.
You need to specify the same name for the `Date` column in both statements. E.g. `DateIn AS [Date]` and `DateOut AS [Date]`. And change the property name in the model accordingly.